# How to specify Linux home directory and shell on a Samba Active Directory server?

Tags: winbind, samba4

This question relates to SAMBA version 4 when used as an Active Directory Domain Controller.

I have everything set up to allow domain users to log in to Linux. However, I have been searching for ages and cannot find how to set a users home directory and shell. I am just getting `/bin/false` at the moment. I have `winbind`, `libnss-winbind` and `libpam-winbind` all installed and working - I can log in but the `/bin/false` shell isn't exactly useful!

I know how to edit the `idmap.ldb`, e.g. to set a user's UID, and I can edit the `sam.ldb` also for other attributes. I have *ADUC* on a Windows box joined to the Samba domain and that works too. I have tried the `template homedir` and `template shell` in the `smb.conf` but nothing has so far worked.

I hope I have missed somethig really simple and the answer is obvious, but I am suffering from *Google Blindless* after much time spent searching for the answer. Even the Samba docs fall short here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set defaults for the home directory and login shell in the `[global]` section of the `smb.conf` configuration file:

```
template shell    = /bin/sh
template homedir  = /home/%ACCOUNTNAME%
```

Note that it is `%ACCOUNTNAME%` and not `%U` as was the case with Samba 3. Similarly, it is `%WORKGROUP%` instead of `%D`. I also discovered that changes to these values are not picked up by `smbcontrol all reload-config` - you have to restart Samba for them to take effect.

You should be able to add RFC2307 attributes to the user's entry in LDAP to specify per-user values but this doesn't work (yet). From the  [Samba Wiki](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Using_RFC2307_on_a_Samba_DC#Advantages):

> currently (4.1.11), Samba servers with AD DC role don't use the standard winbind daemon. This causes winbind & nss-winbind to only fetch UID & GID, not login shell and home. Samba 4.2 will give the possibility to use standard winbind, circumventing this drawback.

So, for the time being at least, we're stuck with system-wide values defined in `smb.conf`.

Comment: A [commit](https://git.samba.org/?p=samba.git;a=commitdiff;h=57228317fc2339b83cccf4b1f3515d8a3b435a3c) fixes this issue for Samba 4.2. It looks like the `%ACCOUNTNAME%` style won't work once this fix is applied. This means that configs will need to be tweaked...